# Create Multiple PDFS from a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a VF page that is designed to export as a PDF. It looks at a parent record: Division__c and uses a component to loop through and create a PDF of all the child records: Region__c.   Currently, if you launch the page you will get a one long multi-page PDF file.  Would there be a way to create separate PDF files for download instead?

Below is a sample of the current page that loops through a component.

```
<apex:page id="MultiRegionPage" standardController="Division__c" extensions="DivisionScoreCardExtension" renderAs="advanced_pdf">
    <apex:repeat value="{!regionList}" var="region">
        <c:SingleRegionCard region="{!region}" heathCheckValues="{!healthCheckValues}" colors="{!colors}"
                            percentContactedA="{!percentContactedA}" percentContactedB="{!percentContactedB}" percentContactedC="{!percentContactedC}" percentContactedD="{!percentContactedD}"
                            openRateA="{!openRateA}" openRateB="{!openRateB}" openRateC="{!openRateC}" openRateD="{!openRateD}"
                            ctrA="{!ctrA}" ctrB="{!ctrB}" ctrC="{!ctrC}" ctrD="{!ctrD}"
                            optOutA="{!optOutA}" optOutB="{!optOutB}" optOutC="{!optOutC}" optOutD="{!optOutD}"  />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with the way your page is currently built, however you can turn Visualforce PDF's into Blobs with `PageReference.getContent()`. You may be able to change your process to have users click on buttons or links that create the Blobs and prompt a user to download.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm